# How to create custom errors in a wrapper class

Tags: visualforce, wrapper-class, adderror

I have a visualforce page for a custom object MyActivity__c. MyActivity__c has two child objects, Actions and Issues. I am using wrapper classes to add/ create new records for the 2 child objects on the page. Each action and issue added has a custom field 'Description__c' that must be filled out before saving. (see below image)
[image]
Rather than having the standard "Error: You must enter a value" message displayed by salesforce, I would like make my own custom error messages. My PageReference save looks like:

```
public PageReference save()
{
    List<Issue__c> issues=new List<Issue__c>();
    for (IssueKeyWrapper wrapper : issueWrappers)
    {
        issues.add(wrapper.is);
    }

    upsert issues;

    List<Action__c> actions=new List<Action__c>();
    for (ActionKeyWrapper wrapper : actionWrappers)
    {
        actions.add(wrapper.ac);
    }

    upsert actions;

    delete issuesToDelete; 
    delete actionsToDelete; 

    return stdCtrl.save();
}
```

and my wrapper looks like:

```
public with sharing class IssueKeyWrapper 
{
    public Integer key {get; set;}
    public Issue__c is {get; set;}

public IssueKeyWrapper(Integer inKey, Issue__c inCs)
{
    is=inCs;
    key=inKey;

    }

}
```

My VF wrapper code looks like

```
  <table class="list" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display: {!IF(issueWrappers.size=0, 'none', 'table')};">
    <tr class="headerRow">
      <th colspan="2" style="width:50%">Issue Description</th>
      <th style="width:5%"></th>
      <th style="width:10%"></th>
    </tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!issueWrappers}" var="issueWrap">
      <tr class="dataRow"> 
        <td colspan="2" >
          <apex:inputField style="width:80%" value="{!issueWrap.is.Description__c}" styleClass="masterClass commentBox2"/>
        </td>
        <td >

        </td>
        <td >
          <apex:commandButton value="Delete" action="{!deleteIssue}" rerender="tableTwo">
            <apex:param name="issueToDel" value="CT{!issueWrap.key}" assignTo="{!issueToDel}"/>
          </apex:commandButton> 
        </td>
      </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
  </table>
  <apex:commandButton value="Add Issue" action="{!addIssue}" rerender="tableTwo" immediate="true" />
```

In the PageReference save method I want to put some logic such as`

```
PageReference result = null; ..... return result;
```

and in the wrapper I'd like to add the logic `

```
if(String.isBlank(is.Description__c))
{
is.Description__c.addError('Hey, don't forget to add a description');
}
else {result = stdCtrl.save();}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, or I wouldn't be here :-) So I guess my question is, how do I correctly declare the *result* variable in the wrapper class, and then how do I connect that to the PageReference save method in my custom controller class? Or is there a better way to do this?

UPDATE: I found a piece of code from the VF cookbook that I'm trying to use in my code. Their example is for the contact object. Is there a way I can do this?

```
public PageReference save()
{
    PageReference result=null;
    Contact cont=(Contact) stdCtrl.getRecord();

    if ( (String.IsBlank(cont.Email)) )
    {
        cont.email.addError('Please enter an email address');
    }
    else
    {
        result=stdCtrl.save();
    }      
    return result;
}
```

Where I'm stuck is with the `else { result=stdCtrl.save();}`. How can I put that in the wrapper and have it be referenced in the PageReference method?

Comment: Can you post some of the Visualforce? Presumably you're not using `<apex:inputField>` for the description?

Comment: Hi @metadaddy . Thanks for answering, I do have <apex:inputField>, please see modified question above

Comment: What behavior are you seeing? An Apex/Visualforce error? The error message not appearing as expected?

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do. Have a look at this resource, focus on how the code is adding the error message on the lead. http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/preventing-duplicate-records-from-saving Also your idea about returning a null page reference. See this question http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63286/best-practices-page-reference-method-return-null . Let me know how you get on and will see if we can help you further.

Comment: @metadaddy Thank you, I'm trying to integrate custom error logic from the VF cookbook in my code (please see the answer I posted below which shows an example of this). My thought is that I should declare the if(isBlank(field)){addError();)} logic in my wrapper class, not the PageReference save method. But what should I do with the 'result' variable? Put it in the method or the wrapper? Or both?

Comment: Moving @RyanWegner's answer into the question, since it's not an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should continue saving the record as it's a valid object.

```
public PageReference save()
{
    PageReference result=null;
    Contact cont=(Contact) stdCtrl.getRecord();
    if(String.IsNotBlank(cont.Email) || String.isNotEmpty(cont.Email)){
            insert contact;
            // Send the user to the detail page for the new contact.
            PageReference result = new Page.Your_VF_Page;
            result.getParameters().put('id',contact.Id);
            result.setRedirect(true);
    }
    else{
       cont.email.addError('Please enter an email address');
    }
    return result;
}
```

Can you also see if you can use this method.

```
PageReference contactPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(contact).view();
contactPage.setRedirect(true);
return contactPage;
```

Personally I think the second option is more elegant.

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, you will need the else ... how you then add the error if the email is blank or empty? My bad, updated my answer, hope it didn`t cause you too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my not so elegant answer, but it works!`

```
public PageReference save()
    {

        PageReference result = null;
        Boolean boolIssue = false;
        Boolean boolAction = false;

        List<VOIssue__c> issues=new List<VOIssue__c>();
        for (IssueKeyWrapper wrapper : issueWrappers)
        {
           issues.add(wrapper.is);

           if(String.isBlank(wrapper.is.Description__c))
           {
               wrapper.is.Description__c.addError('Please enter a description for Issue');
               boolIssue = true;
           }

        }

        if(boolIssue == false)
        {
            upsert issues;
        }

        List<VOAction__c> actions=new List<VOAction__c>();
        for (ActionKeyWrapper wrapper : actionWrappers)
        {
            actions.add(wrapper.ac);

            if(String.isBlank(wrapper.ac.Description__c))
            {
               wrapper.ac.Description__c.addError('Please enter a description for Action');
               boolAction = true;
            }
            if(wrapper.ac.Date__c==null || wrapper.ac.Date__c > dateTime.now())
            {
               wrapper.ac.Date__c.addError('Date must be either day of or in the past');
               boolAction = true; 
            }            
        }

        if(boolAction == false)
        {
            upsert actions;
        }

        delete issuesToDelete; 
        delete actionsToDelete;

        if(boolIssue == false && boolAction == false)
        {
            result = stdCtrl.save();
        }

        return result;

    }
}`
```